# Is "ランタイム時" (runtime-time) acceptable?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-requests, programming

I'm writing a manual, and needed to say something to the effect of "at runtime", as in "Some program debugging can only be performed (or is more efficient or accurate when performed) at runtime." [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase))

I instinctively started typing "ランタイム時に" before realizing that I am essentially saying "at runtime-time", or "at the time of runtime".

Is "ランタイム時" acceptable Japanese? What good alternatives are there in case I don't want to or should not use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ランタイム時に may not be that bad, but feels awkward as you guessed.

And Japanese ランタイム as a noun tends to mean "runtime **library**" (such as JRE, .NET Framework) rather than "run time". For example, "Javaランタイムをダウンロードしてインストールしてください".

The normal way to say "at runtime" in that context would be (プログラム)起動中に, 実行時に, etc.

Comment: （プログラム）実行中 also sounds good to me.